# Transformation on background-clip(ed) text is applied two times in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

Transforming a header text element which has its css property `background-clip: text;` set - is applied 2 times on Firefox (Version 90.0.2).

The same css runs as expected in Chrome.

You can see in the example below that the element (which has a 1px border) is rotated 45degs but the the clipped text is rotated again (to 90 degs) - in Firefox

```css
.center-text {
  margin-top: 25vh;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading-transform {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0066, #0066cc);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.heading-transform:hover {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="center-text">
  <h2 class="heading-transform">
    Should rotate around z only 45degs
  </h2>
</div>
```

This only happens when the `background-clip: text;` is set.

Any possible workarounds to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>This is obviously a bug and I recommend reporting it to [Mozilla](//bugzilla.mozilla.org/)</sub>

This behavior can be **easily** avoided! Simply [`transform`](//dev.mozilla.org/CSS/transform) any parent element.

```css
.center-text {
  margin-top: 25vh;
  text-align: center;
}
.center-text:hover {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.heading-transform {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0066, #0066cc);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-text">
  <h2 class="heading-transform">
    Should rotate around z only 45degs
  </h2>
</div>
```

[<kbd>Interactive Code</kbd>](//jsitor.com/ROQtFQmVQ)

In case `.center-text` cannot be transformed, wrap [`h2`](//dev.mozilla.org/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) in another container.